# Ошибка после смены php

Tags: php

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; database has a deprecated constructor in...
on line 7 . 
На 7-ой строке такое:   class database {
Помогите пожалуйста кто может, как это исправить?

Comment: если у вас конструктор класса называется так же как  и класс, то его (конструктор) нужно переименовать в `__construct`

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать